# Distribution function of maximum of n iid standard uniform random variables where n is poisson distributed

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, convergence

I am studying probability theory on my own and am trying to work the following problem in the book - 
Let $X_1, X_2, . . .$ be independent, $U(0, 1)$-distributed random variables, and
let $Nm \in Po(m)$ be independent of $X_1, X_2, . . . .$ 
Set $V_m = max\{X_1, . . . ,X_{Nm}\} (Vm = 0 \ when\ Nm = 0)$. Determine

(a) the distribution function of $V_m$,

(b) the moment generating function of $V_m$.

(c) Show that $E[Vm] \to 1$ as $m \to \infty$.

(d) Show that $m(1 − Vm)$ converges in distribution as $m \to \infty$, and determine
the limit distribution.

I got stumped at the very first part when trying to find the distribution function of $V_m$. I know that the CDF of $X$ is given by -

$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ x, & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 1 & x > 1 \end{cases}$

This implies that the CDF of $V_m$ should be given by

$F_{V_m}(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ x^n, & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 1 & x > 1 \end{cases}$ where $n \in Po(m)$

Then by differentiating $F_{V_m}(x)$, we get the density function
$f_{V_m} = nx^{n-1}$. Then using conditional probability, we want to find the CDF of $V_m$ and I did the following to get there - 
$P(V_m = x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(V_m = x|N_m=n) . f_N(n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} e^{-m} \frac{m^n}{n!} = me^{m(x-1)}$

The problem is when I try to integrate this over x from 0 to 1,the answer is not 1 which implies that this might not be the correct pdf and hence integrating this may not give me the correct CDF. Incidentally, when integrating this over 1 to x, I get  $ e^{m(x-1)} - e^{-m}$ which is not the correct answer.

I am not sure if I have made a big blunder in my understanding of something or a small goof up. I have looked at  my calculations a few times to ensure that I have not made any silly error. 
I think once I am past this first part, I should be able to get to the rest. I would highly appreciate any help as I feel that this is essential for me to understand before I move forward with my course.
Thanks to anyone ande

Comment: What is the subscript $m$ referring to?

Comment: The subscript $m$ does not refer to anything specific, it is just to show that $V_m$ is the maximum of $n$ uniform random variables where $n$ follows a poisson distribution with parameter $m$. Please let me know if this answers your question. Thanks AdamO.

Comment: $Vm$, by virtue of its construction from uniform distributions, *looks* like it ought to be a continuous distribution. But what is $\Pr(Vm=0)$? (It is nonzero, showing the distribution is not continuous.) Therefore, since $Vm\le 1$, its expectation cannot possibly exceed $1-\Pr(Vm=0)$. This leads to a contradiction of the statement in (c). I suspect some error of interpretation has crept in; for instance, maybe $Nm$ is supposed to have a truncated or shifted Poisson distribution (to avoid the possibility that $Nm=0$).

Comment: I suspect the limit in (c) is $m \to \infty$; that would fix the problem @whuber has pointed out.

Comment: Is it _absolutely necessary_ to use $m$ (in a subscript) to denote the maximum and also to use $m$ as the parameter of the Poisson distribution? I mean there are more than $40$ unused upper-case and lower-case letters breathlessly awaiting a call from you to serve as symbols.

Comment: @jbowman, you are right. It is $m \to \infty$ in both part c and d. My apologies for the error. Corrected it in the question and I think I understand what whuber means. Dilip Sarwate - not sure how that is relevant as it is just a matter of notation but thanks for your comment.

Comment: If your notation is copied from your textbook, then I will merely apply a review attributed to Dorothy Parker to your text: "This is not a book to be put down lightly; it should be thrown with great force."

Comment: @Glen I don't see the problem: "$m$" has not been used in multiple senses in the question as far as I can see. In fact, if we were to stipulate the value of the Poisson parameter once and for all and drop it from the notation, this letter would disappear entirely.  Although it is notationally *richer* to use fonts and alphabets to distinguish different kinds of objects (such as to signal that this is a *parameter*), it is not an error to adopt blander typography.

Comment: @whuber I appear to have misunderstood the notation. Apologies to the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculations in the question look correct, but care is needed because the distribution of $V_\mu$ is not continuous.  (I will use $\mu$ instead of $m$ throughout.)

From first definitions we may find the distribution function (CDF) of $V_\mu$ is

$$F_\mu(x) = \Pr(V_\mu) \le x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \Pr(N_\mu = n) = e^{\mu(x-1)}$$

*provided* $0 \le x \le 1$.  For $x \gt 1$, $F_\mu(x) = 1$ of course.  But for $x \lt 0$, necessarily $F_\mu(x) = 0$.  Here is its graph when $\mu=1$ showing the jump at $x=0$:

[image: Figure]

The moment generating function, $\phi_\mu(t) = \mathbb{E}(\exp(t V_\mu))$, must be computed with similar care near zero.  It can be obtained as a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral,

$$\phi_\mu(t) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{t x} dF_{\mu}(x)$$

via integration by parts as

$$\phi_\mu(t) = e^{t x} F_\mu(x) \vert_{-\infty}^1 - \int_0^1 t e^{t x} e^{\mu(x-1)}dx = e^t - t\frac{e^t - e^{-\mu}}{t+\mu}.$$

As a check, its McLaurin series begins

$$\phi_\mu(t) = 1 + \left(\frac{\mu-1+e^{-\mu}}{\mu}\right) t + \left(\frac{\mu^2 - 2\mu + 2 - 2e^{-\mu}}{\mu^2}\right)t^2/2 + \cdots$$

The constant term of $1$ shows the total probability mass is $1$.  The next two terms will be useful in addressing the rest of the questions.

Comment: thank you very much for this. I highly appreciate your time and help. I knew I was missing something and needed to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks again for this.

Answer (score 1):

notice that since this continous you want to find CDF so going off what you had we have 
$$P(V_{m}<x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(V_{m}<x|N_{m}=n)f_{N}(n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-m}\frac{(xm)^{n}}{n!}=e^{-m}e^{xm}=e^{m(x-1)}$$

Comment: This answer is incorrect because the distribution is *not* continuous.  It gives the wrong values when $x\lt 0$ or $x \gt 1$.

Comment: I think that this is only when $0<x\leq 1$

Comment: @user159813 Although it may seem like a triviality, failing to make that distinction explicit is the root cause of the difficulties expressed in the question.